# CP_EXPORT in class declaration in C++

Tags: c++, class, compiler-construction

What does it mean when a class is declared like this:

```
class CP_EXPORT CP_Window : public CP_Window_Imp
```

What does the `CP_EXPORT` portion mean/imply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CP_EXPORT` is most probably a macro to conditionally export or import the class from a dynamic library.

For example, when using Visual C++, a macro is used to conditionally select between using [`dllexport` and `dllimport`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y1sfaz2(VS.71).aspx).  This allows the same header to be used for both the project building the DLL itself and any projects that link against or load the DLL.

Comment: @James - So also, public CP_Window_Imp in this case means that CP_Window is based upon public CP_Window_Imp?

Comment: @ML:  That means `CP_Window` derives publicly from a base class `CP_Window_Imp`.  It's no different than any other C++ inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using [C-Pluff](http://www.c-pluff.org/reference/c-api/group__symbolVisibility.html)?

Defines:

```
#define     CP_EXPORT
    Declares a symbol to be exported for inter-module usage. 
#define     CP_IMPORT
    Declares a symbol to be imported from another module. 
#define     CP_HIDDEN
    Declares a symbol hidden from other modules.
```

Comment: I thought C-Pluff was a C framework, not sure how class would fit into it (unless there is some C++ layer on top of it)...

Answer (score 1):

`CP_EXPORT` is a macro that expands to some compiler-specific special construction (probably `__declspec` in MSVC or `__attribute__` in gcc) that does something.  To find out exactly what, you'll need to search for the definition of the `CP_EXPORT` macro